# Is it possible to add arrows in sliderInput in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

[image]I am trying to insert arrows in sliderInput vidget in shiny as shown in the attached image. is this doable in shiny?

```
[![sliderInput("capacity", "Growth Rate in Volume:", min=-100, max=100, value=0,post="%")][1]][1]
```

Comment: Please add attached image.

Comment: Please add unattached image

Comment: @cory, do you see the image now?

Comment: You can just do that in HTML, position an image below the slider. Learn more here. http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-tags.html